# Sitecore:Implementing Login Page Using Social Connector Module

Tags: sitecore, facebook-login, sitecore7, sitecore-social-connected

I am using Social Connector Module to Integrate Facebook Login.

How can I integrate this into a page which will be shown to any user when he browses the site for any page and once he logs in with his Facebook credentials, the requested page of the site will be shown.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to make sure they are logged in through Facebook before showing any content? 
After having a quick browse through the [Administrators and Developers guide](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/products/social/12/social_connected_administrators_and_developers_guide_12-a4.pdf) I think you should be able to use a Sitecore `Rule`.

Your `Condition` would be `where the current user is connected to the specific social network`, where you set 'specific' to Facebook. This rule comes with the module. Your (custom) `Action` could be something like 'Set context item to specific item', where specific item is your login page (keep in mind that you probably want to exclude that page for running the `Rule` to prevent infinite loops, assuming your login page is also in Sitecore).

All that's left then is to kick off the rule on page load. To see how Sitecore does this for it's `ConditionalRenderingsRules` you can use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/), and disassemble the `Evaluate` method in `Sitecore.Pipelines.InsertRenderings.Processors.EvaluateConditions`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also achieve this through code:

```
    private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string fbId;
            if (Request.QueryString["authResult"] != null && IsFacebookLogin(out fbId))
            {
                var facebookDataItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("/sitecore/content/Home/FacebookData");
                Response.Redirect(facebookDataItem.Paths.Path.Replace(facebookDataItem.Paths.ParentPath, ""));
            }
        }

public bool IsFacebookLogin(out string fbId)
        {
            fbId = string.Empty;
            if (!Sitecore.Context.User.IsAuthenticated) return false;

            fbId = Sitecore.Context.User.Profile.GetCustomProperty("fb_id");
            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(fbId);
        }
```

In this case, i am doing a redirect if the user is logged in using a facebook ID.
You could also take a look at this blog post for more details on the setup & usage of the module: [Social Connected with Sitecore (Facebook) 1: Setup, Posting messages on content publish & trigger of DMS goals](http://techmusingz.wordpress.com/2014/07/03/social-connected-with-sitecore-facebook-1-setup-posting-messages-on-content-publish-trigger-of-dms-goals/)